# Virtual desktop manager where process spawned from one desktop stay in that desktop

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop, virtual-desktop-manager

All is said in Title. I need virtual desktop manager with one important feature: when process running in one virtual desktop spawns other process, new process must be in same desktop as parent. Not to jump into current desktop or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sysinternals Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) is the right program for me. Current desktop is isolated from junk that spawns in other desktops. Also, it is fast, works OK while machine is under heavy load. No bugs and glitches so far, I have tried few other and all have problems when machine is busy or when I'm debbuging in VS. You can't move programs from one desktop to another, but that is not crucial for me.